# Child Process won't spawn with iisnode

Tags: node.js, powershell, child-process, windows-server, iisnode

I have a MEAN (Angular 2) app working on a Windows Server.
I run my app with iisnode on the server.
The app works fine, but at some point I try to spawn a child process with node (powershell.exe). Everything works fine locally (the powershell script executes successfully) but when I test it from the server URL, the child-process never spawns.
I don't have any error message, the app just kinda pauses itself.
When I run node.js from the command prompt with "node server.js" and I go to : **http://myserver.com:9000** then the app works fine and the child-process spawns sucessfully.

I've tried to put the absolute path of *powershell.exe* but it doesn't work neither.

**localhost:9000** : app works, child-process spawns ans works fine

**myserver.com:9000** : app works, child-process spawns ans works fine

**myserver.com/** : app works, child-process won't spawn, no error message

Here's my **web.config** file :

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
     to be handled by the iisnode module -->
     <handlers>
       <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
     </handlers>     
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="server">
           <match url="/*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

And here's the **route .js** from where I spawn the child-process :

```
child = spawn("powershell.exe",[`some commands`]);
child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
  console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
});
child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
  console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});
child.on("exit",function(){
  console.log("Powershell Script finished");
  //some other commands
});
child.stdin.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, it appeared that the powershell.exe was spawning correctly.
However, the powershell script was supposed to open Powerpoint and do some actions within it. That part wouldn't work, and powershell would raise this error :

`Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program`

This was solved by modifying DCOM config, as suggested here : [How to deploy COM object Microsoft.Office.Interop to IIS so that my C# WCF service reference will work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346468/how-to-deploy-com-object-microsoft-office-interop-to-iis-so-that-my-c-sharp-wcf)