# IIS error (possible related to microsoft word interop or windows update 0x80070070 error)

Tags: c#, iis, office-interop, windows-update

Yesterday I installed office on the production server because my application (C#) is using Microsoft Word Interop. I still got the problem and the part of the application that was using Word Interop (document creation) was not working but the application itself was working fine. In the morning the application was off, and keep throwing "500 error". I uninstalled office but the problem was still there. Finally I performed the windows update and problem solved. Can anyone tell me what could possible go wrong? Here is a part of the windows update log:

> 03:00:56:161   996    1b54    Handler :::::::::::::
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:161     996    1b54    Handler :: START ::  Handler: MSI Install
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:161     996    1b54    Handler :::::::::
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:161     996    1b54    Handler   : Updates to install = 1
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:161     996    1b54    Handler Extracting MSP file stored in CAB filterpack-x-none.cab
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     996    1b54    Handler FATAL: Extraction of CAB filterpack-x-none.cab failed, error = 0x80070070
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     996    1b54    Handler   : WARNING: Operation failed at update 0, Exit code = 0x80070070
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     996    1b54    Handler :::::::::
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     996    1b54    Handler ::  END  ::  Handler: MSI Install
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     996    1b54    Handler :::::::::::::
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     868    ca4 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update D5ACB45E-3FF2-4DD1-AB54-3BA19C4B4440 is "Defaults" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 2467 vs AcceptRate 0.
>   2017-11-16  03:00:56:176     868    ca4 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 6CCF7EC0-EE26-4E69-9700-6F0395CD3E53 is "Defaults" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 2467 vs AcceptRate 0.

**EDIT**

I found that error 0x80070070 in windows update log is related to insufficient disk space. Is this possible related with the "500 error" of the iis server? There is 3GB free space in the main hd, the other hds have more than 5GB free space.

Comment: is your iis pool a named user or just default system/network user

Comment: why don't you post exceptions that you surely capture in your code?

Comment: @BugFinder I can see there are several pools named by the applications names. and for Identity they have "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Sorry but I am not an expert on iis, if this info was insufficient tell me how to find out what you ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy COM object Microsoft.Office.Interop to IIS so that my C# WCF service reference will work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346468/how-to-deploy-com-object-microsoft-office-interop-to-iis-so-that-my-c-sharp-wcf)

Comment: @BugFinder My situation is not that the office interop is not working on iis but the "500 error" I received. And I dont know if its related with the office interop or the error with the windows updates

Answer (score 0):

You should think about changing the way you have coded if you can. Placing office on a backend server to interact behind the scenes for you is notoriously bad. Usually, you let the client deal with document types etc, the only thing that is important is that you ensure IIS has relevant entries in it's MIME Types list to be able to handle the office documents (which I think by default it has anyway).

Comment: What I am trying to do is to generate some word documents using word template and the data that are filled in my application pages. Can you propose a safer way to implement this?

Comment: Here is a link that you might find useful [Creating worddocs without interop](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra)